# Ajax обновление input при нажатии на button кнопки

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
<input type="text" id="input-id<?php echo $tdResultCard['idCart'] ?>" class="inputCountCard" data-up-total="<?php echo $tdResultCard['idCart'] ?>" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo $tdResultCard['cartCount'] ?>">
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <button type="button" id="plus-total" data-up-total="<?php echo $tdResultCard['idCart'] ?>" class="btn btn-light"><i class="far fa-angle-up"></i></button>

    <button type="button" id="minus-total" data-up-total="<?php echo $tdResultCard['idCart'] ?>" class="btn btn-light"><i class="far fa-angle-down"></i></button>
</div>
```

`<?php echo $tdResultCard['idCart'] ?>` нужно для того, чтобы не было похожих полей/кнопок, т.е. каждый button и input имеют уникальный id

```
$('#plus-total').click(function() {
        var data_total = $(this).attr('data-up-total');     
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../ajax/countPlus.php',
            data: 'id='+data_total,
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#input-id'+data_total).val(data);
                loadcart();                 
            }
        });
    });
```

countPlus.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
    include('../connect.php');

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $id = strip_tags($id);
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$id);
    $id = trim($id);

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `idCart` = '$id' AND `cartIp`='{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}'");

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $new_count = $row['cartCount'] + 1;
        $upload = $db->query("UPDATE `cart` SET `cartCount`='$new_count' WHERE  `idCart` = '$id' AND `cartIp`='{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}'");
        echo $new_count;
    }
}
?>
```

Проблема в чем.. Все работает, но только с одним блоком, первым блоком. Не знаю в чем проблема

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под блоками?

Comment: "каждый button и input имеют уникальный id" - `<button type="button" id="plus-total" ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="button" class="plus-total btn btn-light" data-up-total="<?php echo $tdResultCard['idCart'] ?>"><i class="far fa-angle-up"></i></button>
...

$('.plus-total').click(function() {
  ...
```

Comment: смыыыысле?? все заработало, спасибо большое. Поставил бы плюс, но репутация не позволяет. 
Но почему? Можете объяснить?

Comment: @user235631 Исходя из предположения уникальности атрибута `id` на странице, селектор `$('#plus-total')` выбирает максимум один элемент. Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".

Comment: блин. Учту. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: @user235631, [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)